How to set preferred wifi to auto-disconnect from tethering?
I use my android phone as a hotspot on my commute, but I often forget to turn it off when I get to work/home. This is expensive.
I want my laptop to auto-switch to my work/home WIFI when I get to my destination.
The problem may be that my hotspot shows up as a regular wifi connection on my mac, not as a personal hotspot. (I don't know.)
My searching shows that older versions of macOS allowed me to drag-and-drop the network preferences; but it seems that now it uses a scoring system (Source: Apple Support, 2023)
Is there a way I can do this? I haven't found answers to these online:

Can I mark my wifi as a personal hotspot, and will that fix it?
Can I code up a script to affect the scoring of my preferred devices?
Can I code up a script to detect the available wifis and disconnect from my andoid's wifi?
Something else???

Other notes
It is work laptop; ability to run certain software is limited by company policy, but I do have root access.
I am an adept programmer, though AppleScript gives me headaches/heartaches.

Sonoma: 14.6 (23G80)

If you set the hotspot to not auto connect, does that simplify things?

@bmike I have tried this for a few weeks, and only have a 90% success rate: sometimes when I get to work the laptop is still connected to the hotspot. It is that 10% that is dangerous. The 90% lulls into false security, the expensive bill comes from that 10%.

Unexpected bills are the worst. You are correct that setting network service order can’t help as this is about which SSID is preferred. I hope someone with android experience can weigh in. I’m only aware of iOS methods to manage the hotspot which doesn’t help at all since it’s not a change on macOS side other than the auto connect setting I already suggested. Let’s see if a little juice gets more eyes on this…

@bmike's suggestion is a good start on the android side of things, but if the Mac is recognising the hotspot as a regular wifi network, then can't you change within macOS' System Settings to disable Automatically join this network? Go to System Settings > Wifi and click on the info icon next to the hotspot's wifi name, then uncheck the box Automatically join this network. I don't have macOS Sonoma, so I'm not sure if this is an option anymore? But that would be a good starting point.

Additionally, it would be worth checking networking plists in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/. There's a few networking preference plists in this folder that may be able to disable Apple's new way of auto-joining networks, or you could try manually reorder your preferred networks (I think the order of preferred networks is located in the preferences.plist file, and they will be listed by their BSSID/MAC Address). To reorder them, you would need to be comfortable with using defaults terminal command.

You should be able to toggle auto join and not have your Mac decide to join any network.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-wi-fi-settings-on-mac-mh11935/mac


Quickly toggle the automatic join setting for a known Wi-Fi network: Move the pointer over the known network, click the More  button, then choose Auto-Join.

If you leave Auto Join enabled for this SSID, here is the hierarchy of how it should work:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102169


If you manually disconnect from a network, its score decreases. The "most preferred" network is the network with the highest score.

Be sure to manually disconnect from the hotspot more often than you disconnect from your preferred networks.

Personal Hotspot with macOS Ventura reconnects to known private networks in order of most recently joined

Set up another personal network and join that after you disconnect above to bump your android hotspot off the most recently joined podium.
If that fails you, what follows is a less optimal solution, but the only one I can come up with at the moment.
Change the passphrase on android when you need to disconnect a session. If that had bad side effects (like you have to remember it or other devices should continue to tether), you could script forgetting it from the keychain on the Mac side.
More elegant would be an automation to change the SSID. We would need details to help here.  You don’t need AppleScript for that since there are command line and python script options.
First step, can you connect to the home network (away from hotspot) and back manually?
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 networkname

If that doesn’t work, you’ll need to provide us with some details on networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi

I can -setairportnetwork if I provide a password and I can get passwords from security find-generic-password, though I don't know what do do with my work's 802.1X Password, it appears blank.

This is getting places! I haven't figured out how to scan for if my home/office are nearby, but I can use a cron script to set up a state machine to detect the hotspot and cycle the wifi-power after a time limit. (Using networksetup -setairportpower en0 [Off | On])

Please post your partial answer at some point so I can give you the bounty if no one else has an answer.

Thanks to bmike, who pointed me to the networksetup tool.
I haven't found a solution to detect nearby known networks, but this script will power-cycle the wifi after it detects the network has been on for too long.
Note: I am too old of a programmer to go for one-liners; me++ would prefer something more documented and robust.
#!/bin/bash

# Run through a state machine to monitor and disconnect from hotspot network
#
# Run as cron with 2>/dev/null to avoid debug mail
#
# WARNING: uses MacOs tool options, such as date -j

set -eu -o pipefail

declare -r hotspot_network_name="Steely-eyed Missile Man"
declare -r max_hotspot_minutes=45
declare -r disconnect_seconds=15
declare -r state_file=/tmp/hotspot-connection.state

function read_date {
    date -j "$@"
}
function standard_date {
    read_date "$@" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}
function timestamp_to_date {
    standard_date -f "%s" "$@"
}


function state_age {
    timestamp_to_date -v"${1:-+0S}" "$(stat -f "%m" "$state_file" 2>/dev/null || read_date +"%s")"
}

function save_state {
    local -r state=${1%\:}
    shift
    [[ "$1" == ":" ]] && shift

    printf "%s" "$state" > "$state_file"

    if [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; then
        printf ": " >> "$state_file"
        printf "%s\n" "$*" | tee -a "$state_file" >&2
    fi
    printf >&2 "  state=%s\n" "$state"
}

function wifi {
    case "$1" in
        get-ssid) networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | perl -pe 's/^.*:\s*//' ;;
        get-hotspot) if [[ "$(wifi get-ssid)" == "$hotspot_network_name" ]]; then echo On; else echo Off; fi ;;
        get-power) networksetup -getairportpower en0 | grep -Eo "(Off|On)$" ;;
        set-power) networksetup -setairportpower en0 "$2" ;;
        *)
            echo >&2 "Programmer error: unknown wifi command '$1'"
            exit 255
            ;;
    esac
}

declare -r boot_time=$(timestamp_to_date $(sysctl -n kern.boottime | cut -f4 -d' ' | sed 's/,//g'))
declare -r state_time=$(state_age)

if [[ ! -f "$state_file" ]]; then
    save_state off-hotspot : Starting state machine
elif [[ "$state_time" < "$boot_time" ]]; then
    save_state off-hotspot : Starting fresh state machine after reboot
fi

declare now
for i in $(seq 200); do
    now=$(standard_date)

    [[ ! -f "$state_file" ]] && save_state off-hotspot : Starting state machine
    
    # Run the state machine:
    #
    #                               .--------
    #                               V       |
    # [x] -> off-hotspot -> on-hotspot -> disconnecting
    #                ^        |
    #                `-------'
    #
    case "$(grep -Eio '^[a-z_-]+' "$state_file")" in
        off-hotspot)
            if [[ "$(wifi get-power)" == On && "$(wifi get-hotspot)" == On ]]; then
                save_state on-hotspot : Hotspot detected at $now
            fi
            exit 0
            ;;
        on-hotspot)
            if [[ "$(wifi get-power)" == Off ]]; then
                save_state off-hotspot : Wi-fi turned off
            elif [[ "$(wifi get-hotspot)" == Off ]]; then
                save_state off-hotspot : Switched to $(wifi get-ssid | tr '\n' ' ') # Race: ssid has newlines if wifi is off
            elif [[ "$(state_age +"$max_hotspot_minutes"M)" < "$now" ]]; then
                save_state disconnecting : Hotspot time limit of $max_hotspot_minutes minutes breached at $now
                wifi set-power Off
                continue # multi-part state transition
            fi
            exit 0
            ;;

        ## This state handles when something happens to the script after turning the power off
        ## It goes back to on-hotspot (back-dated) just in case the hotspot re-connects
        disconnecting)
            if [[ "$now" < "$(state_age +"$disconnect_seconds"S)" ]]; then
                sleep 5
            else
                wifi set-power On
                save_state on-hotspot : Power-cycled the wifi at $now
                # touch in the past
                touch -d "$(standard_date -v-"$max_hotspot_minutes"M)" "$state_file"
            fi
            continue
            ;;
        *)
            echo >&2 "Unknown state in file $state_file"
            exit 1 # Maybe an operator error, not a programmer error
            ;;
    esac
done

echo >&2 "Looped too many times"
exit 255



Super! Very well documented script
